# Partition a Spark Dataframe based on a specific column and dump the content of each partition on a csv

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark 1.6.2 Java APIs to load some data in a Dataframe DF1 that looks like:

```
Key  Value
A    v1
A    v2
B    v3
A    v4
```

Now I need to partition DF1 based on a subset of value in column "Key" and dump each partition to a csv file (using spark-csv).

Desired Output:

A.csv

```
Key Value
A   v1
A   v2
A   v4
```

B.csv

```
Key Value
B   v3
```

At the moment what I'm doing is building an HashMap (myList) containing the subset of values that i need to filter and then iterate through that filtering a different Key each iteration. With the following code I get what I want but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do that:

```
DF1 = <some operations>.cache();

for (Object filterKey: myList.keySet()) {
  DF2 = DF1.filter((String)myList.get(filterKey));

  DF2.write().format.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true")
      .save("/" + filterKey + ".csv");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to add the `partitionBy`, which will partition the files in the way you want.

```
DF1
  .filter{case(key, value) => myList.contains(key))
  .write
  .partitionBy("key")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/my/basepath/")
```

The files will now be stored under "/my/basepath/key=A/", "/my/basepath/key=B/", etc..