# spllit the csv file into multiplecsv files using spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark.I have the csv file like below. Based on the name(james,hiran,stalin) I want to store the data in a seperate files.

```
100|james|76|23|24|34
101|hiran|84|32|232|13
102|james|78|13|42|32
103|stalin|78|42|13|23
104|hiran|23|21|22|13
105|hiran|23|32|32|32
```

I want process this file based on name(second field).
I want the output like below. james out i want to store in a seperate file. james_output.

```
100|james|76|23|24|34
102|james|78|13|42|32
```

Hiran output should be stored in a seperate file.hiran_output

```
101|hiran|84|32|232|13
104|hiran|23|21|22|13
```

stalin output should be  stored in a seperate file.

```
103|stalin|78|42|13|23
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691710/partition-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-a-specific-column-and-dump-the-content-of-e

Comment: @Khumar, consider accepting few answers to your previous questions.